# In simple multi-layer FFNN only ReLU activation function doesn't converge

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, activation-function

I'm learning tensorflow, deep learning and experimenting various kinds of activation functions.

I created a multi-layer FFNN for the MNIST problem. Mostly based on the tutorial from the official tensorflow website, except that 3 hidden layers were added.

The activation functions I have experimented are: `tf.sigmoid`, `tf.nn.tanh`, `tf.nn.softsign`, `tf.nn.softmax`, `tf.nn.relu`. Only `tf.nn.relu` doesn't converge, the network output random noise (testing accuracy is about 10%). The following are my source code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

W0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200]))
hidden0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W0) + b0)

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200, 200]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200]))
hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden0, W1) + b1)

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200, 200]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200]))
hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1, W2) + b2)

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200, 10]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))
y = tf.matmul(hidden2, W3) + b3

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(10000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(128)
        session.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
        if _ % 1000 == 0:
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
            print(_, session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print('final:', session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
            y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The code outputs something like this:

```
0 0.098
1000 0.098
2000 0.098
3000 0.098
4000 0.098
5000 0.098
6000 0.098
7000 0.098
8000 0.098
9000 0.098
final: 0.098
```

If `tf.nn.relu` is replaced with other activation functions the network accuracy improves gradually (with different final accuracy though), which is expected.

I have read in may textbooks/tutorials that ReLU should be the first candidate as activation function.

My question is why ReLU doesn't work in my network? or my program is simply wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **Relu**  activation function that computes the activation as follows,

**max(features, 0)**

Since it outputs the **max value**, this sometimes causes the **exploding gradient**.

Gradientdecnt optimizer update the weight via the following,

**∆wij = −η
∂Ei/
∂wij**

where **η** is the learning rate and **∂Ei/∂wij** is the partial derivation of the loss w.r.t weight. When **max values** gets larger and larger, partial derivations also gets larger and causes the **exploding gradient**. Therefore, as you can observe in the equation, you need to tune the learning rate (**η**) to overcome this situation.

A common rule is to reduce the learning rate, usually by a factor of 10 each time.

For your case, set the learning rate = 0.001 and will improve the accuracy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, it's caused by gradient exploding problem. I actually tested all activation functions available in TF, activation functions without a upper bound wouldn't converge. BTW, with AdagradOptimizer very activation function converged.