# Tensorflow - Loss increases to NaN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am going though Udacity's Deep Learning Course. The interesting thing that I am observing is that for same dataset, my 1 layer Neural Network works perfectly fine, but when I add more layers my Loss increases to NaN.

I am using following blog post as reference: I am using the following blog post as a reference: http://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning/deep-learning/tensorflow/regularization/

Here is my code:

```
batch_size = 128
beta = 1e-3

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 1024 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_hidden_2 = 512 # 2nd layer number of neurons

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
    # at run time with a training minibatch.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                  shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)


    # Variables.
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, n_hidden_1]))
    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2],stddev=math.sqrt(2.0/n_hidden_1)))
    w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2, num_labels],stddev=math.sqrt(2.0/n_hidden_2)))

    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_1]))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_2]))
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))

    # Learning rate decay configs
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    starter_learning_rate = 0.5

    # Training computation.
    logits_1 = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, w1) + b1
    hidden_layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(logits_1)
    layer_1_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(hidden_layer_1, keep_prob)

    logits_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1_dropout, w2) + b2
    hidden_layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(logits_2)
    layer_2_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(hidden_layer_2, keep_prob)

    # the output logits
    logits_3 = tf.matmul(layer_2_dropout, w3) + b3


    # Normal Loss
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_3, labels=tf_train_labels))

    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step, 10000, 0.96)
    # Optimizer.
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

num_steps = 3001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for step in range(num_steps):

    // some logic to get training data batches

    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
_, l, predictions = session.run(
  [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)

  print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
```

After printing the Loss I see that is increases kind of exponentially to NaN:

`Minibatch loss at step 1: 7474.770508
Minibatch loss at step 2: 43229.820312
Minibatch loss at step 3: 50132.988281
Minibatch loss at step 4: 10196093.000000
Minibatch loss at step 5: 3162884096.000000
Minibatch loss at step 6: 25022026481664.000000
Minibatch loss at step 7: 651425419900819079168.000000
Minibatch loss at step 8: 21374465836947504345731163114962944.000000
Minibatch loss at step 9: nan
Minibatch loss at step 10: nan`

My code is nearly similar to it, but still I am getting NaN.

Any suggestions to what I might have done wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the Relu activation function causes the **exploding gradient**. Therefore you need to reduce the learning rate accordingly (in your case its the **starter_learning_rate**). Moreover, you can try a different activation function also.

Here, ([In simple multi-layer FFNN only ReLU activation function doesn't converge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235290/in-simple-multi-layer-ffnn-only-relu-activation-function-doesnt-converge/47235915#47235915)) is a similar problem as your case. Follow the answer and you will understand.

Hope this helps.