# Why is the loss of my simple NN in Tensorflow nan?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, nan

I have created this simple NN. However, the loss is always 'nan' in every iteration. I have used this algorithm before and did always work.

Here is the code with the respective input aside:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import sys

#load test and train sets
xtrain = pd.read_csv(r'xtrain.csv', decimal=',').astype('float32')
ytrain = pd.read_csv(r'ytrain.csv', decimal=',').astype('float32')
xtest = pd.read_csv(r'xtest.csv', decimal=',').astype('float32')
ytest = pd.read_csv(r'ytest.csv', decimal=',').astype('float32')

# Convert from pandas data frame
xtrain = xtrain.values
ytrain = ytrain.values

n_inputs = 43
n_hidden1 = 300
n_hidden2 = 200
n_outputs = 5

learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 2

batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, n_outputs), name="y")
training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=(), name='training')

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    he_init = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=he_init, name="hidden1")
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, n_outputs, name="outputs")

# Reduce loss
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y))


# Define optimizer
with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope("eval"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1),tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
avg_set = []
epoch_set = []

accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range (training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.

        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: xtrain, y: ytrain})

        avg_cost += sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: xtrain, y: ytrain})
        acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: xtrain, y: ytrain})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: xtest, y: ytest})

        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch: ", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "loss = ", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost), "accuracy-train = ",
                  "{:.9f}".format(acc_train), "accuracy-test = ", "{:.9f}".format(acc_test))
            avg_set.append(avg_cost)
            epoch_set.append(epoch + 1)
    print("Training phase finished")

    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_model_final.ckpt")
```

When running the code I get the following result:

```
 Epoch:  0001 loss =  nan accuracy-train =  0.073428266 accuracy-test =  0.071483918
Epoch:  0002 loss =  nan accuracy-train =  0.073428266 accuracy-test =  0.071483918
Epoch:  0003 loss =  nan accuracy-train =  0.073428266 accuracy-test =  0.071483918
Epoch:  0004 loss =  nan accuracy-train =  0.073428266 accuracy-test =  0.071483918
Epoch:  0005 loss =  nan accuracy-train =  0.073428266 accuracy-test =  0.071483918
Epoch:  0006 loss =  nan accuracy-train =  0.073428266 accuracy-test =  0.071483918
Epoch:  0007 loss =  nan accuracy-train =  0.073428266 accuracy-test =  0.071483918
```

Does anybody have an idea why the loss is always nan? I have tried to find the error for ages and would be really thankful for any help.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245866/tensorflow-loss-increases-to-nan?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed something suspicious. Why is `y` of type `tf.int64` instead of `tf.float32`? When using `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` the labels should be a probability distribution that adds up to `1.0`. If the labels are instead the index of the correct class then you should be using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.