# Evaluation of Regression Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

Hej,

I am trying to write a small program to solve a Regression problem. My dataset is hereby 4 random x (x1,x2,x3 and x4) and 1 y value. One of the rows looks like this:

```
0.634585    0.552366    0.873447    0.196890    8.75
```

I know want to predict the y-value as close as possible so after the training I would like to evaluate how good my model is by showing the loss. Unfortunately I always receive

```
Training cost= nan
```

The most important lines of could would be:

```
X_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 4], dtype=tf.float32)
y_target = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

# Input neurons : 4
# Hidden neurons : 2 x 8
# Output neurons : 3
hidden_layer_nodes = 8

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[4,hidden_layer_nodes])) # Inputs -> Hidden Layer1
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[hidden_layer_nodes]))   # First Bias
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[hidden_layer_nodes,1])) # Hidden layer2 -> Outputs
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1]))   # Third Bias

hidden_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X_data, w1), b1))
final_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_output, w2), b2))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_target * tf.log(final_output), axis=0))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

steps = 10000

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(steps):

        sess.run(train,feed_dict={X_data:X_train,y_target:y_train})

        # PRINT OUT A MESSAGE EVERY 100 STEPS
        if i%500 == 0:

            print('Currently on step {}'.format(i))

    training_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X_data:X_test,y_target:y_test})
    print("Training cost=", training_cost)
```

Maybe someone knows where my mistake is or even better, how to constantly show the error during my training :) I know how this is done with the tf.estimator, but not without. If you need the dataset, let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: Your input and output activations in regression should be 'linear'. Hidden - 'relu' or something else.

And I don't understand your loss function regarding to regression case. Please check it. I suppose your 'nan' is caused by log function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to change my activation function and loss function, but my error is not reaching up to 7000. The activation function used is now relu in the hidden layer and simply no activation in the output layer, so only "final_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_output, w2), b2)" and the cost function "tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(final_output-y_target))". 

I just wonder where the immense error comes from when the labels only vary between 0 and 8?

Comment: What I now understand is that a sigmoid activation function should not be in the output layer, as it can only supply me with values between 0 and 1.
But no matter what I am trying, changing it to no activation function or changing the cost function, the error always gets immensely big!

Comment: For regression cases - only linear activation on the end.

Try another architecture, not 4 -> 8 -> 1, but 4 -> 8 -> 6 -> 3 -> 1, for example.

Maybe it's problem also with randomly generated features? If you have a big amount of rows NN may not fit to it.

Comment: Ah, is the data normalized? If no, apply MinMax scaler to it with either (0, 1), (-1, 1) or (0.1, 0.9).

Comment: Hej! So as I see it, the data is normalized, all x values are between 0 and 1 while y goes from 0 to 10. Or does y also be normalized? And with linear activation you simply mean that there is no special activation function called, just my matmul and add functions, right?

Comment: There is no need to normalize y.

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the **Relu** activation function causes the exploding gradient. Therefore, you need to reduce the learning rate accordingly. Moreover, you can try a different activation function also (for this you may have to normalize your dataset first)

Here, ([In simple multi-layer FFNN only ReLU activation function doesn't converge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235290/in-simple-multi-layer-ffnn-only-relu-activation-function-doesnt-converge/47235915#47235915)) is a similar problem as your case. Follow the answer and you will understand.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were right, changing the learning_rate helped, but it was even better to just change the activation functions to sigmoid and the optimizer to AdagradOptimizer and received a loss of 5.0 which is good I think assuming that the values are all random.
In the tf.estimator examples, the loss or error is continuously out during evaluation. What would I do to constantly see the changing error while going through the dataset?